Deploy using FTP not working. Folder created but file not uploaded
When I am trying to deploy it always shows this error:
Note: this code created all folders of my project but did not upload files after creating all folders it shows the error please solve this issue.
My problem:

Folder created
File not uploaded
My code
on:
push:
branches:

main



name:  Deploy using FTP
jobs:
web-deploy:
name:  Running Deployment Process
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name:  Get latest code
uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Install node.js 18
    uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: '18.x'

  - name:  Build Project
    run: |
      npm install
      npm run build

  - name:  Sync files
    uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
    with:
      server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
      username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
      protocol: ftps

Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/setup-node@v2. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/.
Error:
[my code:](https://i.sstatic.net/V0WTsw2t.jpg)
